# Why "noch" in "Ist da noch frei?"

Tags: phrase, particle

Somebody mentioned this as a common phrase to ask for a seat next to someone.

Why "noch" in there? Why is it more usual than simply "ist da frei"?

Comment: Wer sagt, dass es besser ist?

Comment: If most people would prefer it over the other, I consider it better. Better from the perspective of someone learning German.

Comment: Und wenn die Mehrheit ohne Schulterzucken sagt "in keinster Weise", statt "in keiner Weise"?

Comment: Yep, I'd be interested in knowing that too. There's usually a reason people talk how they talk, even if it's not codified in the rules. There. I fixed my question for you. :) No more "better".

Comment: Danke. Würdest Du denn darauf wetten, dass "noch frei" häufiger ist als nur "frei"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ist da frei"? simply means "is the seat free?".
"Ist da **noch** frei?" means "is the seat **still** free?".
Most people would consider the second version slightly more polite.

Comment: Imagine "is this seat **still** free" followed by the unspoken "... or is it **already** occupied".

Comment: @puck: Falsche Dichotomie. Imagine  "is this seat free" followed by the unspoken "... or is it occupied".

Comment: @PiedPiper: Darf man das "Most people" so verstehen, dass Du dich da nicht anschließen willst? Dass es ein höflicher Hinweis ist, dass die zweite Form nicht besser ist?

Comment: @userunknown Ich finde beide Fragen akzeptabel, aber ich vermute, dass  ich in der Minderheit bin

Comment: @PiedPiper so I should understand "noch" as temporal? I don't understand how adding "still" makes it more polite.

Comment: @MladenJablanović Yes, "noch" is temporal here. I think there is a general feeling that padding a short question with 'filler' words makes them seem more polite, but maybe I'm wrong. You  can certainly use either version

Comment: @PiedPiper I am also curious about _noch_  which appear in some non-obvious for me places, eg. "Schönen Tag noch!".  Why is it there?

Comment: @maoizm I think it's another example of the same thing.